# When Using IE Mailto Form No Content Appears

Tags: html

I am using `mailto()` to allow submission of work information by customers.  When using IE (only) no email content appears.

Code:

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="mailto: Group@gmail.com?subject=TI Providers" ENCTYPE="text/plain">

<div class="auto-style1">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="USERNAME:" style="width: 188px">&nbsp; Name <BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ORGANIZATION:" style="width: 189px">&nbsp; Organization <BR>
<input type=""text" NAME="ADDRESS:" style="width: 189px">&nbsp;&nbsp; Address <br>
<input type=""text" NAME="PHONE:" style="width: 189px">&nbsp;&nbsp; Phone No. <br>
<input type=""text" NAME="EMAIL:" style="width: 189px">&nbsp;&nbsp; Email <br><br>


    <span class="auto-style3">T Training</span><span class="auto-style2">
    </span> <br>
<TEXTAREA NAME="TRAUMA TRAINING:" ROWS="10" WRAP="hard" style="width: 310px">
</TEXTAREA> <br> <br>


    <span class="auto-style3">TModalities: (for therapists)</span><o:p></o:p>
  <BR>
<TEXTAREA NAME="TRAUMA MODALITIES:" ROWS="10" WRAP="hard" style="width: 305px">
</TEXTAREA>


<INPUT NAME="redirect" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="default.htm">
<INPUT NAME="NEXT_URL" TYPE="hidden" VALUE="default.htm">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type=""text" NAME="EXPERIENCE:" style="width: 63px">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <span class="auto-style3">Years Of Experience</span> <br><br>
    <br />
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear"> <br />
    <br />
</div>
</FORM>
```

Comment: That's cuz IE's shiat ;) just kidding... It works on some browsers but in some dont, you should handle the form on your Server and not an extern Service.

Answer (score 0):

[`mailto:` form actions do not work reliably enough](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) to use on the WWW. Switch to a server side solution instead.